# Listening for RabbitMQ and running flask on same server

Tags: python, flask, rabbitmq

I have a Flask application as such

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from mq_handler import MessageBroker
import pika

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
mb = MessageBroker(connection)



class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def get(self):
        mb.run()
        return {'hello': 'world'}


class LogHandler(Resource):
    def get(self, table):
        return {'TableName': table}




api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/')
api.add_resource(LogHandler, '/log/<string:table>')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I have added a MessageBroker class to handle all my rabbitMq messages

```py
import pika
import json


class MessageBroker:
    def __init__(self, connection):
        self.connection = connection
        self.channel = connection.channel()

    def run(self):
        self.channel.start_consuming()
        self.channel.basic_consume(queue='logs',
                              auto_ack=True,
                              on_message_callback=self.handle_log)
        self.channel.start_consuming()

    def handle_log(self, ch, method, properties, body):
        decoded_content = body.decode('utf-8')
        json_payload = json.loads(decoded_content)
        print(" [x] Received %r" % json_payload['message'])
```

I have tried different solutions, but have can I get both services to run simultaneously on the same server? can somebody explain that please?

In general.. how is it possible to have several services running listening on my flask server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about running the consumer on an end-point will be a good idea. Because, when you start a consumer it runs an IO loop to fetch and process messages from the server continuously. The loop will not exit unless it is done externally or any exception in the message processing causing the connection to close. Can you please state your scenario for running the consumer in the end-point?